# Form submit when window unload

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a HTML form  with id = testsForm. When the user tries to leave the page, I have written a basic function to ask the user for confirmation using the window.onbeforeunload function. Now, Im trying to submit the form, if the user chooses to leave the page when asked. This is what I have tried:

```
submitted=false,saveBeforeUnload=false;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
       if (!submitted) {
             saveBeforeUnload=true;
             return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
       }
 }

setInterval(function() {
              if (saveBeforeUnload) {
                       saveBeforeUnload = false;
                       document.getElementById('testsForm').submit();
              }
}, 500);
```

I don't know why this doesn't seem to work. Please help me out.

Comment: You have a design error: submitting a form that the user doesn't want to submit will not win you friends. All you should be doing is asking if the user wants to stay on the page. Disclaimer: I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643636/5217142) regarding how to ask the user if they want to leave.

Comment: I am giving a pop -up to the user asking if they want to leave. If they wish to, thats when the form should be submitted. Thats what im trying to do

Comment: You can't create a popup in modern browsers. In _some_ you can provide the prompt given to users asking if they really want to leave, but not in Chrome. Why are you insisting on submitting the form when users actually want to discard unsaved work (no answer required) ?

Comment: Basically, Im creating a form which is a quiz, and the user gets only one go at it. If the candidate wishes to leave the page, after confirming when the prompt is given, the form with the questions answered should be submitted. Thats the overall functionality of the page

Comment: Untested, but make sure you're setting `e.preventDefault()` and `e.returnValue`.  See the example here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload  It isn't enough to just return a string from that function.

Answer (score 1):

Ethically I'm not sure that's something you should do unless it's clearly stated or an internal application.

However, if your not familiar with Ajax do some research around it. You should be able to gather the data and submit it back to the server within the onbeforeunload event.

Hope that helps, be sure to let us know how you go.

Comment: Agree on the ethical bit

Comment: Hey, I am giving a pop -up to the user asking if they want to leave. If they wish to, thats when the form should be submitted. Thats what im trying to do. Anyways, ill look into Ajax. Could you give me a brief idea how to do it in ajax. Thanks

Comment: You won't get your AJAX request to complete in `onbeforeunload`.  The best you can do is use the new Beacon API.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an older question but in case anyone else is having this issue, I wanted to add a solution.

From the original posters comments: "Basically, I'm creating a form which is a quiz, and **the user gets only one go at it**. If the candidate wishes to leave the page, after confirming when the prompt is given, the form with the questions answered should be submitted. That's the overall functionality of the page."

This is a valid function for the page but I think the user is recording this information at the wrong **TIME**. He should update the record to save that it was accessed when the page is first **LOADED**. He would then update the record again with the information that the user entered.

That would resolve not being able to submit the form on an unload and not save any information that the user did not want saved. He might want to add information on the page that the link has been used and cannot be reused or the "popup" can show that.

I know that is not a programming answer but sometimes it is about WHEN to use the tool not HOW.

Answer (score -1):

The Ajax idea from Mayhem50 is worth looking into.

Not sure why you want the **setInterval**, but you can remove some extra code and put your **form submit** command inside the `onbeforeunload`:

```
var submitted = false;
  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (!submitted) {
      document.getElementById('testsForm').submit();
      return "You are about to leave this order form. You will lose any information...";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you mind posting your whole code, so we can take a look?

Comment: A form submit is not going to work in `onbeforeunload`.  Test your code before posting.